# How to use update & join in OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, db2, linked-server

I have several rows in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table in

```
ConfirmTable (ItemID, Barcode)
```

and more rows in DB2 header file

```
O1 (ItemId, barcode, ProductionUnit, OwnerName, Delivered, Qty)
```

and Detail file

```
O2 (ItemId, barcode, Address, ItemName, Delivered, TotalLines)
```

I want to update DELIVERED status in O1 and O2 files to 'YES' if the `ItemID` and `Barcode` exist in `ConfirmTable`. I am trying to use following query but it seems showing following error.

> OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "LINK_DB" returned message "Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing."

Code:

```
UPDATE OQ 
SET OQ.Delivered='YES'
FROM OPENQUERY(LINK_DB, 'SELECT * 
                         FROM XXXXR.HLIB.O1 O1O 
                         LEFT JOIN XXXXR.HLIB.O2 O2O ON O1O.ItemID = O2O.ItemID 
                         WHERE O1O.Qty > 0') OQ 
INNER JOIN 
    ConfirmTable CT ON CT.Barcode = OQ.Barcode
```

I also tried the following format of update still it did not work for me.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28390846/OPENQUERY-in-sql-server-linked-server.html

Comment: So you wanted to update table which is remote via linked server?

Comment: Yes! FYI: Select query works perfectly fine with the above query.

Comment: Agree, but what you want achieve you rather need `EXECUTE (sql) AT linked_server`. Second thing OQ is result of JOIN not single table so how do you want update it if it was locally?

Comment: Sorry! Just realise. Removed ItemID from there The only way to see item is by Barcode.

Comment: First of all which table should be updated XXXXR.LIB.O1 or XXXXR.HLIB.O1?

Comment: Both tables,but I am not sure I can update both of them together.

Comment: Generally speaking, DB2 will not allow you to update a result set that is a join of two or more tables.

Comment: Thanks Lads2025 and mustaccio for give it a try. 
Does it seem correct to you? 

Begin TRANSACTION;
UPDATE OQ '
SET OQ.Delivered='YES'
FROM OPENQUERY(LINK_DB, 'SELECT * 
                         FROM XXXXR.HLIB.O1 O1O WHERE O1O.Qty > 0') OQ
INNER JOIN 
    ConfirmTable CT ON CT.ItemID = OQ.ItemID


UPDATE OQ 
SET OQ2.Delivered='YES'
FROM OPENQUERY(LINK_DB, 'SELECT * 
                         FROM XXXXR.HLIB.O2 O2O) OQ2               
INNER JOIN 
    ConfirmTable CT ON CT.Barcode = OQ2.Barcode
COMMIT

Answer (score 7):

It's an old post but I had to deal with it now.

Don't use join in OPENQUERY.

Instead, for example, do something like this:

```
UPDATE OQ 
SET OQ.Delivered='YES'
FROM OPENQUERY(LINK_DB, 'SELECT * FROM XXXXR.HLIB.O1') OQ
JOIN OPENQUERY(LINK_DB, 'SELECT * FROM XXXXR.HLIB.O2') QQ2 ON QQ.ItemID = QQ2.ItemID  
INNER JOIN ConfirmTable CT ON CT.Barcode = OQ.Barcode
WHERE QQ2.Qty > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, I fixed it long back.

Comment: Thanks for posting, @Denn isn't the only one trying to get this to work, as the viewcount on this page indicates.